# Iterate through Multiple Variables in a Nested Loop

Tags: python

I am trying to get iterate through last 10 days and verify if "accounts" is in row [0] within that time frame. Wheni test the code it's running the else statement instead of the IF statement. I made sure that accounts IS in row[0] inside my table so that the IF statement can run...but its not.

FYI row 4 is a dates column in my table so i am matching it with the variable i (last 10 days)

```
day_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
qselectall = '''select account_number, proc_date, email_address, 
cy_day,to_char(load_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from sumb_email_conf'''
dupcursor.execute(qselectall)
start_date = datetime.date.today()
end_date = start_date + 7 * day_delta
for i in range((end_date - start_date).days):
    i = start_date - i * day_delta

df = DataFrame(accounts_sheet)
         email_address = df[df['cycle_day'] == 
         current_cycle_day].email_address_test
         account_numbers = df[df['cycle_day'] == 
         current_cycle_day].account_number
         for account, email in zip(account_numbers, email_address):
             print(account)
             for row in dupcursor.fetchall():
                 if str(i) in row[4] and account == row[0]:
                     print("Yes there are DUPS")
                     break
                 else:
                     print("No there are no DUPS")
                     break
```

Comment: `in` row[0] or `==` row[0]?

Comment: If you are working with dataframes, try to avoid loops unless its the only way to go. What's your specific question?

Comment: Note that the `break` are useless in your code because you break in each case

Comment: @Vishnudev My question is that the else statement is running even though i DO have variable accounts in row[0]

Comment: @txemsukr if i dont use break then i get about 10-15 "No There are no Dups:"

Comment: But here you are only testing if the first row is a dup of your row, and that's probably not what you want. You probably need to add a boolean, `false` by default and set to `true` in the `if` part. Then, if your boolean is `true` outside of the `for` you `print` that there are dups, else you `print` that there are no dups.

Comment: @txemsukr you are rright because when i print "account" i only get one row. Do i have to set i or account to false outside the loop?

Comment: Initiate it to `false` before the `for`, and then do what I said in my previous comment ;)

Comment: @txemsukr account = False then inside the if statement account=True?

Comment: Exactly, that's what you should do

Answer (score 0):

@txemsukr  I must be doing something wrong becaue the else statement is still running.

```
day_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
qselectall = '''select account_number, proc_date, email_address, 
cy_day,to_char(load_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from sumb_email_conf'''
dupcursor.execute(qselectall)
start_date = datetime.date.today()
end_date = start_date + 7 * day_delta
for i in range((end_date - start_date).days):
    i = start_date - i * day_delta


df = DataFrame(accounts_sheet)
    email_address = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].email_address_test
    account_numbers = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].account_number
    account = False
    for account, email in zip(account_numbers, email_address):
        for row in dupcursor.fetchall():
            if str(i) in row[4] and account == row[0]:
                account = True
        else:
            print("There are no dups")
            sql = '''INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf (proc_date, cy_day, account_number, email_address, load_date)
                                                                                    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
            values = (yesterday, str(current_cycle_day), account, email,
                          str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
            insertcursor.execute(sql, values)
            connection.commit()
        print("There are Dups")
```